# How to determine wrong domain/IP

Tags: java, networking, validation

I have field on my web application that allow entering **domain/IP** addresses.
User can specified by misteken the following values:

```
 10.10.10.
```

or

```
-domain.com
```

Both values are incorrect regarding RFCs about IP and Domain names.
I use the following validators from guava's library for validation :

```
 InetAddresses
 InternetDomainName
```

My goal is to determine wheter user specified wrong IP or Domain and show messages regarding to it.

```
Ex: if user specifes "-domain.com". Alert shoud be appear with message "Wrong domain name is specified".
```

I've already used `^[0-9\\.]*$` for determining wrong ip's, but I am not sure whether it was correct one.

Could you suggest some

Comment: If you are already using com.google.common.net.InetAddresses, why do you need additional regex at all?

Answer (score 0):

Validate IP address by using below regular expression pattern:
^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.
([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$

Validate Domain names using below regex pattern:
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9].[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/

But certain vaild domain names will fail the above test like http://google.com

Thanks

Comment: It does not work for me: I've tried with valid and invalid IPs, like 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1. with first regex, also with correct and incorrect domain addresses like: -google.com and google.com with second regex. In which cases it should matches?

Comment: Please see, my answer above.

Comment: public boolean validateIPAddress( String ipAddress ) { String[] tokens = ipAddress.split("\\."); if (tokens.length != 4) { return false; } for (String str : tokens) { int i = Integer.parseInt(str); if ((i < 0) || (i > 255)) { return false; } } return true; }.Try this code.